# WSO2-ML Error create model

Tags: wso2, wso2-ml

when i try create model with "decision-tree" dataset example, generated the below error. WSO2 Machine Learner version is: 1.2.2 .

[2017-01-11 18:21:02,284] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.impl.MLModelHandler} -  Failed to build the model [id] 9
org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.exceptions.MLModelBuilderException: An error occurred while building logistic regression model: For input string: ",06"
        at org.wso2.carbon.ml.core.spark.algorithms.SupervisedSparkModelBuilder.buildLogisticRegressionModel(SupervisedSparkModelBuilder.java:322)

suggestion?
Thanks,
Emanuele

Answer (score 0):

**resolved** - the problem is caused by  italian setting system operation. That use "comma separated" character for decimal and not "dot" character. I have resolved changed the settings.